# Windows 10 is ignoring time changes on Samba 4 DC

Tags: samba, windows-domain, ntp

I have got and VM with a Samba 4 installed as AD DC. It is also NTP server and the time on the server is correct. Tested with `ntpdate -q ntp-server`, which gives the correct time and date:

```
ntpdate -q dc01
-> server 10.0.0.25, stratum 2, offset -0.000003, delay 0.02570
->  5 Apr 00:29:02 ntpdate[19581]: adjust time server 10.0.0.25 offset -0.000003 sec
```

Today I started my Windows 10 client first time after the winter to summer time change and it's still in winter time. I tried following, to no avail:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update
-> The command completed successfully.

net stop w32time
-> The Windows Time service is stopping.
   The Windows Time service was stopped successfully.

net start w32time
-> The Windows Time service is starting.
-> The Windows Time service was started successfully.

w32tm /resync
-> Sending resync command to local computer
-> The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

I assume 'Sending resync command to local computer' means tell the NTP client to connect to the NTP server (the AD DC VM) to get the time correction.

Obviously nothing happens.

As additional hint and maybe of value: The "Internet Time" tab in the "Date and Time" configuration dialog is not showing, what seems to be normal in case of domain clients.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 4):

Finally some random w32time related posts let me to the solution. First, logging helps:

```
w32tm /debug /enable /file:c:\temp\ntpDebug.log /size:102400 /entries:0-300
w32tm /resync
-> Sending resync command to local computer
-> The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

In the logfile, there had been the AD DC listed as time server, but it still claimed to have no time server to ask.

The error message "Tx timestamp not returned and may be unsupported on the current network interface" let me to following [microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/ta-in/help/875424/time-synchronization-may-not-succeed-when-you-try-to-synchronize-with).

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"dc01,0x8 dc02,0x8" /syncfromflags:MANUAL
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /resync
-> Sending resync command to local computer
   The command completed successfully.
```

Obviously Samba 4 doesn't like Windows 10 symmetric active mode requests. Hence, use 0x8 to switch the time client to client mode.

Don't forget to switch off logging:

```
w32tm /debug /disable
```

Here we go :)

Comment: This is a nice solution for my issue, where time.windows.com stopped working, last success at 15 Dec 2022. No alternative changed just by windows settings (time.nist.gov, or 'pool.ntp.org') worked at all. So, switching to 'pool.ntp.org', with the steps by the microsoft support article pointed above, worked and time could be synced again in my windows 10 installation.

Answer (score 1):

We solved it by following the [Samba Wiki / Configuring Time Synchronisation on a DC](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Time_Synchronisation). In our case (Samba AD running on Debian/buster) `ntpsigndsocket` was missing and then incorrect in the `ntp.conf` file.

`ntp.conf` should contain this line:

```
ntpsigndsocket  /var/lib/ntp_signd/
```

The socket path can be determined via:

```
% sudo lsof -Un | grep signd
samba       525            root   23u  unix 0x0000000029f51b41      0t0 15061 /var/lib/samba/ntp_signd/socket type=STREAM
```

Our Windows Domain (Windows Server 2019) already had refused to sync its time against the domain controller:

> Time Provider NtpClient: No valid response has been received from
> domain controller %1 after 8 attempts to contact it. This domain
> controller will be discarded as a time source and NtpClient will
> attempt to discover a new domain controller from which to synchronize.
> The error was: %2

We fixed it by stopping the time provider service, re-registering it and restarting the service again:

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
```

(A `w32tm /resync` might be enough.)

The domain controller should then be shown with `w32tm /query /source`.

This post was also really helpful: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/ntp-on-samba-4-dc-not-syncing-with-windows-10-workstations-4175685516/#post6187657

Answer (score 1):

if you follow the [samba setup instructions](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Time_Synchronisation#With_ntpd) you need to add **mssntp** to the config and also set permissions on the ntp_signd folder then you should not need to manually alter the windows clients if that are configured with default settings. It is unlikely the fault is with windows and is most likely a misconfiguration of ntp.conf. Remember to restart the ntp service after making changes.

I found [this guide](https://blog.svedr.in/posts/configuring-ntpd-for-a-samba-4-domain/) useful

The path provided to ntp_signd in ntp.conf in the other answer is also not correct for me (ubuntu) and should be `ntpsigndsocket /var/lib/samba/ntp_signd`

Note:
When you make changes to w32tm you do need to use the /update parameter for the changes to take effect:
`w32tm /config /update`
`w32tm /resync`

You should set your clients like this (this is the default config):
`w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update`

Note that windows will time out after 8 attempts for 15 mins as seen in the event log
Time Provider NtpClient: No valid response has been received from domain controller DC1.example.com after 8 attempts to contact it. This domain controller will be discarded as a time source and NtpClient will attempt to discover a new domain controller from which to synchronize. The error was: The peer is unreachable.

You can debug with the following command:
`w32tm /debug /enable /file:C:\temp\w32time.log /entries:0-116 /size:10000000`
and remember to disable it with:
`w32tm /debug /disable`

to check the ntp service is listening / running
`sudo lsof -i:123`
and you can configure logging in ntp.conf
`logfile         /var/log/ntp`